# kdb/Q How to update single row in table?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to find out how I can update a single value in a single, specified row in my table.

What I need is to go from this:

table - before

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |

to this, specifically targeting row with Index at 2:

table - after

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | c |

I think something like this is a start: `table: update Value:?[Value="b";"c";Value] from table[rowIndex]`, but this only updates and returns the one row, I'm trying to find a way to keep the table as is and ONLY alter the value in the given row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a where clause to only update where the condition is met, as long as there is only one row that meets the condition:

```
table: update Value:"c" from table where Value="b"
```

If there is more than one row meeting the condition you may want to filter using `rowIndex`:

```
table: update Value:?[Value="b";"c";Value] from table where i=rowIndex
```

OR you might be able to skip the conditional:

```
table: update Value:"c" from table where i=rowIndex
```

Comment: Does the "i" variable refer to the index? In the examples above, there actually is no column called "Index", I'm just suing it to show what the index is of each row. Can I use "i=0" to get the first row of the table?

Comment: Yes, `i` is a virtual column and `i=0` can be used to get the first row of the table.